# i3wm running in Arch Linux guest (VirtualBox) stops auto-resizing

Tags: linux, arch-linux, virtualbox, i3

I'm trying to get Arch Linux to work on VirtualBox. I've followed the instructions on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_guests) and the OS boots fine (running `linux-lts kernel`, with  `virtualbox-guest-dkms` Guest Additions installed). After installing i3, I've added the following to `~/.xinitrc`:

```
VBoxClient-all
exec i3
```

This appears to work, but does the auto-resizing only once. After that, the `Auto-Resize Guest Display` menu and `Seamless Mode` in host VirtualBox menu become disabled. 
What I found out, is that if I kill the VBoxClient process and re-initiate it, the auto-resize functionality starts to work again, but disables as soon the first resize event occurs.

```
killall VBoxClient
/usr/bin/VBoxClient-all
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Arch recently and the problem seems to be fixed! However, prior to that, I just settled with defining an alias in my .zshrc file:

```
alias resize='killall VBoxClient && VBoxClient-all'
```

So whenever I needed to fix the sizing of my screen, I just typed that command in my terminal. Not really the solution I was asking for, but it still helped out a lot.